# Async tasks and data collections using Task.Run without waiting

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

In a WCF service I am dispatching multiple requests to other API/Libraries and I wanted to not wait for these tasks to complete, so I ended up using Task.Run to complete asynchronous tasks *without waiting for completion*.

The code looks like this:

```
var someList = new List<int>();                
var i = 0;
foreach (var item in group)
{
     i++;
     var variableOne = i;
     Task.Run(async () =>
     {
              // Does the **variableOne** and variable **i** equals the latest value assigned to it, or the value at the time of calling?**
              // Can someList be prematurely garbage collected before the tasks run, because the original function containing all the code shown in the example has completed (since Task.Run is not awaited)?
              await OcrUtility.ApiOcrUpload(
              new OcrUtility.ApiOcrUploadContract()
              {
                  documentList = item.Documents
              });
      });
}
```

My three questions are:

1. Can someList (or any other object referenced by the Task content) be prematurely disposed/garbage collected before the tasks content run?
2. Does the variable **i** inside the task equals the latest value assigned to it, or the value at the time of calling?
3. I'm used to Javascript, and I know that if I do use `setTimeout()` in javascript I need to use some kind of **context-copy** trick in order to keep the current value of `variableOne` at the time of calling, so it does not get set as the latest value assigned to `variableOne` when the "task" (function in the case of JS) is being executed.
   Do we need to do that kind of copy with C# or does it come with built-in context-copy? Does .Net evaluates which variables are being used, and create a copy of them at the time of calling?

Comment: `I wanted to not wait for these tasks to complete` is almost certainly a design mistake. You should carefully consider how exceptions are surfaced, and how you would handle deployment of updates. In particular, this pattern is especially dangerous if WCF is hosted by ASP.NET.

Comment: Not really, I do not want clients to have a Timeout if the main action succeeded. It's a job of the webservice to get the job completed to the end, and it has to handle on its own the exceptions thrown by them. I guess you wanted to say IIS and not ASP.Net?

Comment: @MykaEyl the name doesn't matter but the code is really dangerous. You are trying to emulate a long running job using fire-and-forget tasks. Such background tasks can be killed by IIS whenever the application pool is recycled, or when the hosting process terminates.

Comment: Yes I know that about IIS, it's like any other hosting system, but what would you suggest to counter that effect? Am I wrong or IIS won't kill it unless there's a crash or a recycling forced by an admin or program?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Recycling isn't forced, it's a reliability mechanism that kicks in periodically. First, why should the *client* timeout? The service can run as long as it needs to. It's the *client* that needs to adjust its timeout value or await for a response asynchronously. Unlike web sites, WCF (or any web service) is *expected* to run long jobs.

Comment: WCF supports one-way services, something I had forgotten about. They are suited to long running scenarios.

Comment: Ok, but I understand your points about logging exceptions and the fact that the client should set the appropriate timeout. I'll wait for these tasks to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `List<T>` is not disposable, so no, it cannot be disposed.  If you meant garbage collected, no objects will ever be collected if you can ever access them through managed code; this is only ever something to even thing about when dealing with `unsafe` code.
2. It has the value of the variable at the current point in time, not the value of the variable when it was closed over.  Closures close over *variables*, not *values*.
3. The behavior is the same here; closures close over variables, not values.  This is why you needed to create `variableOne` instead of using `i` in the lambda.  If you closed over `i` you'd get the current value of `i`, but as you're taking a copy of that value *inside* the loop, and never mutating that variable (`variableOne`), the value of the variable when you close over it is always the same as the value of the variable when the delegate is invoked.

You can of course trivially test this using the following code:

```
int i = 3;
Func<int> f = () => i;
i = 42;
Console.WriteLine(f());
```

If it prints `3`, then it means closures close over *values*.  If it prints `42` then it tells you that closures close over *variables*.

Answer (score 1):

WCF allows you to create [one-way services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730149(v=vs.110).aspx), where the client doesn't wait for a response so it doesn't time out.

In short, you set the [IsOneWay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isoneway%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your method's [OperationalContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to `true`.  The following snippet from the docs demonstrates this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class OneAndTwoWay
{
  // The client waits until a response message appears.
  [OperationContract]
  public int MethodOne (int x, out int y)
  {
    y = 34;
    return 0;
  }

  // The client waits until an empty response message appears.
  [OperationContract]
  public void MethodTwo (int x)
  {
    return;
  }

  // The client returns as soon as an outbound message
  // is queued for dispatch to the service; no response
  // message is generated or sent.
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
  public void MethodThree (int x)
  {
    return;
  }
}
```